# Accelerometer in SpriteKit not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

I am making a game in which you should be able to move the player by tilting the device left and right. I'm using the accelerometer for this. In my GameScene class I call movementSetup in my Player class which does this:

```
-(void)movementSetup {
  self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
  self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2;
  [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
  self.accelerometerData = self.motionManager.accelerometerData;
}
```

Then in the update method in my GameScene class I call my movement method in my Player class:

```
-(void)movement {
  CGVector moveLeftVector = CGVectorMake(-1, 0);
  CGVector moveRightVector = CGVectorMake(1, 0);
  if (fabs(self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)<1) {
      SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveBy:moveLeftVector duration:0.2];
      [self.aPlayer runAction:moveLeft];
  }
  if (fabs(self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)>1) {
      SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveBy:moveRightVector duration:0.2];
      [self.aPlayer runAction:moveRight];
  }

}
```

I also declared 3 properties in my player class a SKSpriteNode *aPlayer, a CMMotionManager *motionManager and a CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData.

When I run this and test this on my device (iPhone 6) the sprite node just slowly moves to the left regardless of me tilting the device. Why?

EDIT: I also got a memory warning after a while

Comment: running a new action on every accelerometer event is total overkill, instead just apply the acceleration to the node's position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what I did wrong:

First of all move the self.accelerometerData = self.motionManager.accelerometerData to the movement method so it gets updated every frame.

Then change the lesser than and equal than values to something lower than 1 because the accelerometer won't get values higher than 1;